# Run a script at each startup of my EC2 instance

Tags: linux, ubuntu, aws

I have a EC2 instance at AWS. I have installed docker in it.

Sometimes I have to reboot my instance but I need each time to restart my container with my `./up` script.

How can I make a script witch will be executed at each reboot of my instance so I won't need to execute my script manually ?

Comment: Other than a reboot entry in crontab?

Comment: You can add your script to rc.local.. that should run your script on startup..

Comment: I don't have a rc.local in my instance @ryekayo what should I do?